# How to access this chartink button using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to access this Download CSV button at the bottom of this link
but it is not working

https://chartink.com/screener/large-cap-stocks

I have tried using this

```
dr.get("https://chartink.com/screener/vwap-bof-prev-high-wick")
dr = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdriver selenium\chromedriver.exe")
dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn.btn-default.buttons-excel.buttons-html5.btn-primary")).click();
```

I am getting the below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-11e8443d6aed> in <module>
----> 1 dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn.btn-default.buttons-excel.buttons-html5.btn-primary")).click();

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote it in Java not Python. Also add some wait prior to clicking. There's two of the selectors you used you can just get the a tag with that text.

```
time.sleep(5)
dr.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Download csv']").click()
```

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?